# Update multiple columns based on if one column has a certain value

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have a question regarding a PSQL database.

I am a little bit stuck.

The logic is:

```
IF table1.column_1 IS var
THEN table1.column_2 = foo
AND table1.column_3 = bar
```

Essentially, if one column contains a specific value, then how can I update other columns?

I am new with PSQL, so please be gentle! I have looked at Case statements, but it seems you can't have an Update inside a case. If an if/else is what I need, could someone provide a simple example?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like:

```
UPDATE table1
SET column_2 = 'foo',
    column_3 = 'bar'
WHERE column_1 = 'var';
```

Comment: I am such an idiot - I should hide my face in shame! Thank you for the simple solution!